# Problem on Characteristic function in Heston model

Tags: finance-mathematics, heston

I know the Heston model .In this model, we have

$$f(\Phi,x_t,v_t)=\exp(C_j(\tau,\Phi)+D_j(\tau,\Phi)+i * \Phi * x_t)$$

How can we extract the Characteristic function  as follows

$$f(\Phi_1,\Phi_2,x_t,v_t)=\mathbb{E}[\exp(i * \Phi_1 * x_T+i*\Phi_2*v_T)]$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Heston model is represented by the bivariate system of stochastic differential equations
\begin{align}
  & dS_t=rS_tdt+{\sqrt\upsilon_t}S_t dW_1(t) \\
 & dv_t=\kappa(\theta-v_t) dt+\sigma{\sqrt v_t}dW_2(t) \tag 1\\
&\mathbb{E}[dW_1(t),dW_2(t)]=\rho dt
\end{align}
set $x_t=\ln S_t$, By application of Ito's lemma, we have
\begin{align}
  & dx_t=\left(r-\frac12 v_t\right)dt+{\sqrt\upsilon_t} dW_1(t) \\
 & dv_t=\kappa(\theta-v_t) dt+\sigma{\sqrt v_t}dW_2(t) \tag 2\\
\end{align}
Let $B_1(t)$ and $B_2(t)$ be two  independent Wiener processes, we have
\begin{align}
  & dx_t=\left(r-\frac12 v_t\right)dt+{\sqrt\upsilon_t} dB_1(t) \\
 & dv_t=\kappa(\theta-v_t) dt+\sigma{\sqrt v_t}\left(\rho\,dB_1(t)+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}dB_2(t)\right) \tag 3\\
\end{align}
Now we can write the Heston model as follow
$$dy_t=\mu(t,y_t)dt+\Sigma(t,y_t)dB_t\tag 4$$
where
$$y_t=\left( \begin{matrix}
   {x_t}  \\
   {v_t}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$
$$\mu(t,y_t)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   r-\frac{1}{2}{{v}_{t}}  \\
   \kappa (\theta -{v_t})  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
\\
\Sigma (t,y_t)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   \sqrt{{{v}_{t}}} & 0  \\
   \sigma \rho \sqrt{v_t} & \sigma \sqrt{1-{{\rho }^{2}}}\sqrt{{{v}_{t}}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\tag 5$$
and
$$B(t)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{B}_{1}}(t)  \\
   {{B}_{2}}(t)  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$
The drift $\mu$ and the matrix $\Sigma\Sigma^{\text{T}}$  can both be written in the affine form
$$\begin{align}
  &\quad\,\, \mu (t,{{y}_{t}})={{\alpha}_{0}}+{{\alpha}_{1}}{{x}_{t}}+{{\alpha}_{2}}{{v}_{t}} \\ 
 & \Sigma {{\Sigma }^{\text{T}}}(t,{{y}_{t}})={{\beta}_{0}}+{{\beta}_{1}}{{x}_{t}}+{{\beta}_{2}}{{v}_{t}} \\ 
\end{align}\tag 6$$
where
$${{\alpha }_{0}}=\left( \begin{matrix}
   r  \\
   k\theta   \\
\end{matrix} \right),\,{{\alpha }_{1}}=\left( \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right),{{\alpha }_{2}}=\left( \begin{matrix}
   -0.5  \\
   -\kappa   \\
\end{matrix} \right)\tag 7$$
and
$${{\beta }_{0}}={{\beta }_{1}}=\left( \begin{matrix}
   0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right),{{\beta }_{2}}=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & \rho \sigma   \\
   \rho \sigma  & {{\sigma }^{2}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\tag 8$$
The result of [Duffie, Pan, and Singleton (2000)](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Disasters/DuffiePanSingleton%20jumps%20Econometrica%2000.PDF) is that the characteristic function has the log-linear form
$$f(\phi_1,\phi_2,x_t,v_t)=\exp\left(A(\tau,\phi_1,\phi_2)+B(\tau,\phi_1,\phi_2)x_t+C(\tau,\phi_1,\phi_2)v_t\right)$$

---

**Note**

> Duffie, Pan, and Singleton (2000) show that the characteristic
>   function of a wide class of multivariate affine models (of which the
>   Heston model is a special case) has a log linear form .

**For more details, see it:**

- [Affine concatenation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229760662_Affine_Concatenation)

Comment: Thanks. Really why do we use bivariate characteristic function?

Comment: By time-dependent approach,Heston model was enhanced.