# Options on realized volatility / variance

Tags: volatility, variance, heston, characteristic-function

If I'd like to price options on variance/volatility in the Heston model. Is MC simulation and/or finite difference the only way to do it? Or is there an analytical expression for the probability density function of realized variance in the Heston model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic function of the Heston model is known in closed form. To obtain the option prices you have to perform numerical integration though.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.139.3204&rep=rep1&type=pdf

you can also check the already asked (and answered) question

[Problem on Characteristic function in Heston model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31063/problem-on-characteristic-function-in-heston-model)

which refers to this paper

[Duffie, Pan, and Singleton (2000)](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Disasters/DuffiePanSingleton%20jumps%20Econometrica%2000.PDF)

Now regarding your original question: here is a reference for options on variance which seems reasonable to me

[Pricing Options on Realized Variance in Heston
Model with Jumps in Returns and Volatility](http://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/[Journal%20of%20Computational%20Finance,%20Sepp]%20Pricing%20Options%20on%20Realized%20Variance%20in%20Heston%20Model%20with%20Jumps%20in%20Returns%20and%20Volatility.pdf)

they price a number of vol derivatives semi-analytically where only a numerical integration is necessary. This should help you

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Sepp's paper. That was what I was looking for. Kind of surprising that there are multiple papers dealing with the characteristic function of the joint spot and instantaneous volatility process, but few focusing on the quadratic variation distribution.